# codeigniter session only work for one page not for other pages linked to the page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have login with username and password to the page it will login successfull and that page has link for other pages but i am setting username to session variable but it will say session is not availabe.

```
    verifylogin.php

    <?php 

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {



 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('login/user','',TRUE);
 }

 function index()
 {
   //This method will have the credentials validation
   $this->load->library('form_validation');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
     //Field validation failed.&nbsp; User redirected to login page

     $this->load->view('index');

   }
   else
   {
      //$this->load->view('home_view');
     //Go to private area
     $password = $this->input->post('password');
     if($this->check_data($password))
     {
     redirect('login_f/home', 'refresh');
     }
     else
     {
         $data['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
         $data['rannum'] = $this->send_confirm_email();      
         $this->load->view('/login/verify_code2',$data);
     }
   }

 }

 function check_database($password)
 {
   //Field validation succeeded.&nbsp; Validate against database
   $username = $this->input->post('username');
   $this->load->model('login/user');


   //query the database
   $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);
   $value = $this->user->user_type($username);


   if($result)
   {


     if($value == 0)
     {  
         $sess_array = array();
         foreach($result as $row)
         {
           $sess_array = array(
             //'id' => $row->id,
             'username' => $row->username
           );
           $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
         }
         return TRUE;
     }


   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
     return false;
   }
 }

    function check()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }





}
?>

home.php


<?php 
session_start(); //we need to call PHP's session object to access it through CI
class Home extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
 }

 function index()
 {
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
     $this->load->view('login/home_view', $data);
   }
   else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page


     redirect('login_f/login', 'refresh');


   }
 }

 function logout()
 {
   $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
   session_destroy();
   redirect('login_f/home', 'refresh');
 }

}

?>
```

Comment: Could you post some of the relevant code? Thanks.

Comment: i think this is relevent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance the user is redirected to a different server? The session is available only on the same domain. from the PHP manual:

> A visitor accessing your web site is assigned a unique id, the so-called session id. This is either stored in a cookie on the user side or is propagated in the URL.
>
> The session support allows you to store data between requests in the $_SESSION superglobal array. When a visitor accesses your site, PHP will check automatically (if session.auto_start is set to 1) or on your request (explicitly through session_start() or implicitly through session_register()) whether a specific session id has been sent with the request. If this is the case, the prior saved environment is recreated.

I've used [this manual](http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/01/scalable-login-system-for-codeigniter-ion_auth), maybe it will help you find your error.

If everything looks ok, one more thing to check is whether the session files are being created. There might be a permissions problem. to check this, create a page:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

make sure that the `session.save_path` directory exists and is writable, and that `session.auto_start` is set to on if you want to start the session automatically. you can also start it manually by running the command [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php);

to set it on, in the `php.ini` file (usually located in /etc/php.ini):

```
session.auto_start = 1
```

to change the sessions folder, change `session.save_path`:

```
session.save_path = "/path/to/session_files"
```

Comment: my session.auto_start is off is it a problem

Comment: is important to on that

Comment: how to on session.auto_start

Comment: session.cookie_lifetime also 0

Comment: depends on your needs.. for example i don't want users to stay connected. i want them to log out automatically after being idle for X time, so i never used `session.cookie_lifetime = 0`..

Comment: How ever i dont have the sesssion i used this for getting the username  $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
  $this->session->set_userdata($data);                                                                                                                    <?php echo $this->session->userdata('username');?>                                                                                                      its print the username for other pages but i have logout and can access those pages what am i to do

Comment: use `session_unset();` and `session_destroy();` to logout the user